# Condition for right handed invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an m by n matrix and is right invertible, such that there exists and an n by m matrix $B$ such that $AB = I_m.$ Prove that $m\leq n.$

I'm not really sure how go about this problem; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: Show that for every $\mathbf y\in \Bbb R^m$, you can solve the equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf y$. This means there are no inconsistent systems, and so the rank of $A$ must be $m$.

Comment: How would I show that I can always solve that equation? After all, there are inconsistent systems, i.e. sytems whose augmented matrix have a pivot in the last column?

Comment: Use the equation $AB=I_m$ to give a formula for $\mathbf x$.

Comment: I don't fully understand; could you expound on what you mean by that?

Comment: Hint: Multiply that equation by $\mathbf y$ and regroup.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $m>n$. Complete $A$ with rows of zeros to get an $m\times m$ matrix called $A_0$. Complete $B$ with columns of zeros to get another $m\times m$ matrix $B_0$.

Then $A_0B_0=I_m$, but this is a contradiction because $\det A_0=0$, that is, $A_0$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

View $A$ as a map from an $n$-dimensional vector space to an $m$-dimensional vector space. The first thing to notice is that $A$ must be surjective, for $I_{m}$ is clearly surjective onto its image, and had $A$ not been, then $I_{m}$ couldn't have been either.

But if $A$ is surjective, then the dimension of the space of the image must be less than or equal to the dimension of the space of the source. Thus $m\leq n$. To further clarify this point: $n=rk(A)+nl(A)=m+nl(A)\geq m$. The rank of $A$ is $m$ since it is surjective, as mentioned above.